# calc mean by n lines together

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need to calculate the average of all columns by three lines only, like

```
0.9 0.7 4.1             12.0
0.9 0.7 4.1             12.5
0.8 0.7 4.1             12.4
0.7 0.3 4.1             11.2
0.7 0.3 4.1             11.2
0.8 0.3 4.0             11.1
```

So I should get two lines only, i.e.

```
0.86 0.7 4.1 12.3
0.73 0.3 4.03 11.16
```

Can anyone drop me a simple script for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
here is an awk script for you dear.

BEGIN{
FS=" ";
N=3;
sum1=0;sum2=0;sum3=0;sum4=0;count=1;
}
{
 if(count%N != 0 )
 {
  count++;
  sum1 = sum1 + $1;
  sum2 = sum2 + $2;
  sum3 = sum3 + $3;
  sum4 = sum4 + $4;
 }
 else
 {
  sum1 = sum1 + $1;
  sum2 = sum2 + $2;
  sum3 = sum3 + $3;
  sum4 = sum4 + $4;
  printf("%f %f %f %f\n",sum1/N,sum2/N,sum3/N,sum4/N);
  sum1=0;sum2=0;sum3=0;sum4=0;count=1;
 }
}
END{
}
```

hope it will help you. run it as :

```
awk -f <name of this awk script> <your input text file>
```

becaue , if your text file contain x lines of input where x is not a miltiple of N , then your x%N lines will going to miss from your output. The above script will give partial result but correct of no of lines in the text file isnt a multiple of N. To handle this, you can add the follwoing lines in the END section of the script.

```
END{
count-=1;
if(count!=0)
{
printf("Last 'x'=%d lines in the text file such that x <     N\n",count);
printf("%f %f %f     %f\n",sum1/count,sum2/count,sum3/count,sum4/count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you: (GNU awk?)

```
 awk -vCONVFMT='%2.2f' '{a+=$1;b+=$2;c+=$3;d+=$4}!(NR%3){$1=a/3;$2=b/3;$3=c/3;$4=d/3;a=b=c=d=0;print}' file
0.87 0.70 4.10 12.30
0.73 0.30 4.07 11.17
```